# Replace matched strings in text

Tags: python, string, match

From a text file as input, I need to replace the words that were found in an input list. 
The output is the same text file, but the words that were found, need to be replaced with, say: `<repl>matached_word</repl>`.
I have constructed a series of loops for this, but I cannot replicate the same text file. I tried with a 20 line text file of strings, but the output has millions of duplicated rows.

Here's an example.
An input text file can be:

```
bucharest sdfsadf
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
vienna etc
etc
can
sdfds
22
rdf

fd
paris
Paris
```

The code I tried is:

```
# input files
input_file = r"....\input_txt_test.txt"
list_names = ["Bucharest", "bucharest", "vienna", "Paris", "buc"]
out_file = r"....\output_txt_test.txt"

# Perform replacement
with open(out_file, 'w') as outfile:
    with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
        text = f.readlines()
        for line in text:
            line_sp = line.split(" ")
            for name in list_names:
                for word in line_sp:
                    if name in word:
                        strreplace = '''<repl>%s</repl>''' % name
                        repl = line.replace(name, strreplace)
                        outfile.write(repl)
                    else:
                        outfile.write(line)
```

I expected this output:

```
<repl>bucharest</repl> sdfsadf
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
<repl>vienna</repl> etc
etc
can
sdfds
22
rdf

fd
paris
<repl>Paris</repl>
```

But this is what I get:

```
bucharest sdfsadf
bucharest sdfsadf
<repl>bucharest</repl> sdfsadf
bucharest sdfsadf
bucharest sdfsadf
bucharest sdfsadf
bucharest sdfsadf
bucharest sdfsadf
<repl>buc</repl>harest sdfsadf
bucharest sdfsadf
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
sofia sdf sdf dsf 
vienna etc
vienna etc
vienna etc
vienna etc
<repl>vienna</repl> etc
vienna etc
vienna etc
vienna etc
vienna etc
vienna etc
etc
etc
etc
etc
etc
can
can
can
can
can
sdfds
sdfds
sdfds
sdfds
sdfds
22
22
22
22
22
rdf
rdf
rdf
rdf
rdf





fd
fd
fd
fd
fd
paris
paris
paris
paris
paris
ParisParisParis<repl>Paris</repl>Paris
```

Also, I have the "buc" string in the list_names, but no word matches that string, and It's still being inserted into the output file.
How can I perform this matching and file-writing? Thanks!

Comment: `outfile.write(line)` should be `outfile.write(word)`?

Comment: I just tried the suggestion, and it writes about 60 rows.

Comment: You're writing a whole line to the output file every time you're comparing two words. So every line is going to appear in some form 5*(number of words) times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you read for each line `line` in your input.txt, if you find a word is in given `list_names`, you replace that word in `line` with a new one. After that, you save `line` to the output file and keep checking:

```
# input files
input_file = r"....\input_txt_test.txt"
list_names = ["Bucharest", "bucharest", "vienna", "Paris", "buc"]
out_file = r"....\output_txt_test.txt"

# Perform replacement
with open(out_file, 'w') as outfile:
    with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
        text = f.readlines()
        for line in text:
            line_sp = line.split(" ")
            for word in line_sp:
                if word in list_names:
                    replaced_word = "<repl>{}</repl>".format(word)
                    line = line.replace(word, replaced_word)
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: I would do `for line in f: line_sp = line.strip().split(' ')` instead of `readlines` just to avoid reading it all into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Read your file and replace your input words for  words..

```
yourListOfWords = ['a','b','c']
yourFile = open('PATH','r')
newFile = open('PATH_NEW','w')
yourFile.read().splitlines()

for line in yourFile:
    for word in yourListOfWords:
        newline = line.replace(word,'<rep>'+word+'</rep>')
        newFile.writelines(newline +"\n")
```